# TensorFlow JS: How to train a model with X and y of differing dimensions?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Here's my goal: take two arrays of prices and volume and put them together into sequences of historical data and predict a price.

Essentially, we end up with an X that is [7, 2] shape.  The y is just the price, shape [1].

I think I've (finally) got the X and y cooperating.  How to craft the input to take the firstSequence and predict a price?

Code:

```
async function trainAndPredict(priceData, volumeData) {
  const sequenceLength = 7; 
  
  const { values:normalizedPrices, min:minPrice, max:maxPrice } = normalizeData(priceData.map(p => p[1]));
  const { values:normalizedVolumes, min:minVolume, max:maxVolume } = normalizeData(volumeData.map(v => v[1])); 
  
  const sequences = createSequences(normalizedPrices, normalizedVolumes, sequenceLength); 
  const firstSequence = sequences.shift();  
  
  normalizedPrices.splice(-(sequenceLength + 1));  

  const X = tf.tensor(sequences); 
  const y = tf.tensor(normalizedPrices); console.log("y.shape: "+ y.shape);

  const model = tf.sequential(); 
  model.add(tf.layers.flatten( { inputShape: [X.shape[1], X.shape[2]] } )); console.log("A2");
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1 })); 

  model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });

  await model.fit(X, y, { epochs: 100 });

  const input = tf.tensor(firstSequence); 
  const normalizedPredictedPrice = model.predict(tf.expandDims(input, 1));
  const predictedPrice = denormalizeValue(normalizedPredictedPrice, minPrice, maxPrice);

  return predictedPrice.dataSync()[0];  
}
```